# Правильно ли оформлена цитата?

Tags: цитирование

Оригинал:

> По социальному положению до революции в своем хозяйстве имел: дом, три
> амбара, надворные постройки, пасеку 40 ульев. Занимался откормом гусей
> отправляя в Ростов по 700 штук. Отец был сельским старостой. После
> революции: дом, три амбара, пасека 20 ульев. В 1931 году раскулачен,
> жена судима на 5 лет за контрреволюцию, имущество изъято.

Цитата:

«…До революции в своем хозяйстве имел: дом, три амбара, надворные постройки, пасеку 40 ульев. Занимался откормом гусей отправляя в Ростов по 700 штук… После революции: дом, три амбара, пасека 20 ульев. В 1931 году раскулачен… имущество изъято».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Целое предложение, убранное из текста, в цитате обычно отмечается не просто многоточием, а многоточием в угловых скобках: <...>.